# Solving merge conflicts in Sublime Merge

Tags: git, sublimemerge

I have downloaded Sublime Merge and I would like to know how to merge the conflicts

I have run  `git pull` and got conflicts

Answer (score 1):

In the current version it should be fairly simple. Take a look at a very similar case with conflicts after cherry picking (it's basically the same with `git pull`):

[image: sublime merge conflict resolution]

After notifying you of conflicts you immediately get a list of files that need conflict resolution.

You go through all of them by clicking "Resolve" and "Stage" after resolving. Then just commit and you're done.